# Virtual storage increases for a continuously running application

Tags: c++, c, embedded-linux

Before I ask my question let me explain my environment:

1. I have a C/C++ application that runs continuously (Infinite loop) inside an embedded Linux device.
2. The application records some data from the system and stores them in text files on an SD-card (1 file per day).
3. The recording occurs on a specific trigger detected from the systems (each 5 minutes for example) and each trigger inserts a new line in the text files.
4. Typical datatypes used within the application are: `(o/i)stream`, `char` arrays, `char*`, `c_str()` function, `struct`s and `struct*`, `static string` arrays, `#define`, `enums`, `FILE*`, `vector<>`, and usual ones (`int`, `string`, etc.). Some of these datatypes are passed as arguments to functions.
5. The application is cross compiled with a custom GCC compiler within a Buildroot and BusyBox package for the device's CPU Atmel AT91RM9200QU.
6. The application executes some system commands using `popen` in which the output is read using the resulting `FILE*`

Now the application is running for three days and I noticed an increase of 32 KB byte in the virtual storage (VSZ from the `top` command) each day. By mistake the device restarted, I launched the application again and the VSZ value started from the usual value on each fresh start (about 2532 KB).

I developed another application that monitors the VSZ value for the application and it is scheduled using `crontab` each on each our to start monitor. I noticed at some point during the day the 32 KB I noticed happened 4 KB each hour.

So the main question is, what would be the reason that the VSZ increase ? Eventually it will reach a limit causing the system to crash that is my concern because the device have approx. 27 MB of RAM.

Update: Beside the VSZ value, the RSS also increases. I ran the application under `valgrind --leak-check=full` and after the first recording I aborted the application and the following message appeared many many times!.

```
==28211== 28 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 15 of 52
==28211==    at 0x4C29670: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28211==    by 0x4EF33D8: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==28211==    by 0x4EF4B00: char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==28211==    by 0x4EF4F17: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==28211==    by 0x403842: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 (gatewayfunctions.h:28)
*==28211==    by 0x403842: _GLOBAL__sub_I__Z18szBuildUDPTelegramSsii (gatewayfunctions.cpp:396)
==28211==    by 0x41AE7C: __libc_csu_init (elf-init.c:88)
==28211==    by 0x5676A94: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.19.so)
```

The same message appears, except that the line with `*` appears with a different file name. The other thing I notice, line 28 of file `gatewayfunctions.h` is a static string array declaration, this array is used in two files only. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Probably a memory leak, no way of telling without seeing some code

Comment: Can you either run the application through a memory tracker like Valgrind on the embedded device or port the application to a platform where you can run valgrind?

Comment: @IshayPeled I think if it is a memory leak it should appear with the first recording, happened with me when I used to have most of the code as pointers.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm having a problem connecting to the device, but in the meanwhile, I don't remember that the device has valgrind support. How do I port the application to my PC where I can run valgrind ? see my update now It might help.

Comment: The size of VSZ is not so interesting, as RSS size - what happens with RSS?

Comment: @user1641854 What is RSS ? I can't find it in the `top` command on the device.

Comment: @3bdalla RSS - resident set size of the process. You can get it via ps -orss <pid> .

Comment: @user1641854 Unfortunately the device only supports `ps -l` and `ps -w`

Comment: I guess for memory leak or fragmentation issue.

Comment: My first step would be to speed up the application so that it runs (much) faster - say record something every 10ms instead of every 5 min. This will make the leak much more obvious. Using virtual size or resident size from top or similar is not as reliable as "make it crash by doing the thing over and over again" to inform you of "there is a real leak".

Comment: @3bdalla another way to check RSS: grep VmRSS /proc/<pid>/status

Comment: What you need to determine is if you are actually leaking, or the problem is that you are actually leaking (or accumulating data), or just happen to use a little more memory over a longer run of the application.

Comment: If VSZ increases for some days then stabilizes, it can be caused by fragmentation but is harmless. If it increases with no limit, you should fix it, be it a memory leak or fragmentation issue. But you can also decide to restart the application on a weekly base .

Comment: @user1641854: It has 660 KB, Should I monitor it continuously ?

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Precisely! But I already tried running it every few seconds, the increase rate is the same but the device still crashes.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: This can be determined by a long run (for few weeks maybe to see if it stabilizes or not. But unfortunately the device cannot be restarted, it should keep running since I already monitor the files size and delete them if necessary.

Comment: @3bdalla yes, monitor it like a VSZ. If you see constantly increasing values - it definitely means you have a memory leak. If RSS is not increasing, but VSZ is increasing - then it seems that you have some fragmentation problems, possibly with your memory allocator.

Comment: Can anyone see the latest update on the post ?

Comment: Looks like it's recording a lot of string allocations. Which, doesn't sound like a memory leak as such. However, you need to not abort your program [add something to stop the main loop after X number of iterations instead]

Comment: @MatsPetersson: I left the application running on Thursday with a cron job of an application that monitors the VSZ and RSS for the main application. I ran the application on my PC using valgrind and some warning messages appeared on a line that contains a `static string[]` declaration. I will check the monitor results on Sunday and see what happened.